# How to find k-nearest neighbors in kd tree for large k (k = n)?

Tags: machine-learning, knn, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

I am currently implementing a kd tree from scratch in python, and applying the knn algorithm to it. I have constructed the tree and have the algorithm to find 1-nn, but am unsure how to use this to get the k-nearest neighbors. I find the nearest neighbors by comparing each node with the correct attribute, and then moving down the appropriate child/ side of the node. After completing that node, I do a pruning technique and figure out whether it's worth looking at the other child of the node to see if I get a better distance (closer neighbor). I have read online that I can just save the k-best distances into a max heap and then that'll give me the k-nearest neighbors. I have implemented this, but I find that it is flawed, maybe I'm not doing it correctly. This brings me to my question.

Let's say my k is huge, k = n, where n is the number of items or nodes in the tree. If I traverse the tree to the nearest neighbor, and I save all the best distances along the way, my algorithm will not traverse all the nodes in the tree. It will choose the best path to get to the nearest node, and with pruning it will neglect nodes, so it will not be able to visit k nodes if k = n. Therefore, my max heap will only have the best distances of the number of nodes I traversed, and I won't be able to traverse k nodes, so it won't have the k-nearest neighbors. How do I combat this problem? Or is there another way, am I doing something wrong?

** I know using a large k with a kd tree is not the best practice, but I have been tasked with providing the accuracy of all k from k=1 to k=n.